# Grothendieck topology on a scheme equivalent to the circle

Tags: gn.general-topology, schemes, grothendieck-topology, sites

Suppose a class of morphisms of schemes is reasonable enough so that we can associate a small site to any scheme (just like small étale site). Is there a simple class of morphisms such that there is a scheme whose small site is homeomorphic to the small site associated to $S^1$ (considered as a topological space)? By a homeomorphism of sites I mean a [continuous](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00WV) equivalence of the underlying categories (with a continuous inverse).

See [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/60641/138661) for some remarks about etale morphisms (I do not think that etale site would work, however).

Comment: Do you mean the subset of closed points? Otherwise the answer is clearly no...

Comment: Answers [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/2770/30186) explain exactly which spaces are underlying spaces of a scheme. $S^n$ isn't such a space, since its quasicompact open subsets don't form a basis. I think this also will work for the space of closed points which abx is mentioning.

Comment: @Wojowu oh I see. So the sphere itself is quasi-compact, but there is no basis of quasi-compact opens, right?

Comment: Right. No proper open subset of the sphere is quasi-compact.

Comment: The edit doesn't change the fundamental obstruction (the underlying locale of the étale topos of a scheme is a locally spectral space, so it cannot be $S^1$).

Comment: What is your goal in asking this question?

Comment: @S.Carnahan just for fun